How to open a Github folder in Google Colab?
I have a GitHub repository with the following general structure
repository/
-- topic1/
-- topic2/
-- topic3/
---- data/
---- src/
------ notebook3.1.ipynb
------ notebook3.2.ipynb
------ notebook3.3.ipynb
-- topic4/
-- topic5/
...

The notebooks belonging to the same notebook may access the same data. For example, one notebook may preprocess some data and save to data/ and then a subsequent notebook loads and works with this preprocessed data. Also the notebooks might import some utility methods provided by .py files in the src/ folder.
I make this repository available to my students and currently always assume that the students clone or download the repository and run the notebooks locally. This works of course perfectly fine.
Now I wonder if there's an (easy) way to also share those notebooks to less tech-savvy users who do not have their own Jupyter setup locally running on their PCs or laptops. Ideally, I would like to take the Github link for a whole topic and share it with others. For example, if I share "some" link for topic 3, users should see
topic3/
-- data/
-- src/
---- notebook3.1.ipynb
---- notebook3.2.ipynb
---- notebook3.3.ipynb

in their Google Colab.
I know that it is reasonably straightforward to open individual notebooks hosted on Github in Google Colab, e.g., by replacing "github" with "githubtocolab" in the URL. However, unsurprisingly this breaks codes such as

from src.utils import plot_data(df)

df=pd.read_csv('data/demo.csv')


I also assume that notebooks running on Colab this way are independent? For example, even if notebook3.1.ipynb and notebook3.2.ipynb see some data/ folder, would it be the same?
Is there an easy and systematic way to share a complete folder with multiple notebooks and subfolders on Google Colab? Or is this simply not possible?

"Now I wonder if there's an (easy) way to also share those notebooks to less tech-savvy users who do not have their own Jupyter setup locally running on their PCs or laptops." The Jupyter Community, which is open source unlike Google's Colab & Google is also famous for ending useful offerings abruptly, offers a solution for this: MyBinder.org. You simply point the service at the repo and it builds an image from it using repo2docker and spins up a temporary session for you all without logging in. You can add configuration files to specify an environment with dependencies already ....

 installed. You can see a simple example here. Press the 'launch binder' badge to get started. You'll see the example here launches with a particular notebook open at the start because of ?filepath=index.ipynb at the end of the launch URL. The URL can also be used to start with different interfaces. Here is an example with RStudio vs. Jupyter. (Overlook that the Jupyter link there needs fixing; I filed an issue long ago ...

 here.)You can even specify JupyterLab vs. Jupyter Notebook with the launch URL or even switch by hand editing the URL once you know the pattern. There is a way to use the menu to go from the Jupyter Notebook flavor interface to JupyterLab for those not looking to edit a URL on the fly. Because the entire repo gets cloned, you should be able to use everything as if it was on your local machine. Advise your users to download anything useful they make back to the local machine as the remote session is temporary and there is ...

 no persistence. Depending on your needs you can also use JupyterLite now which offers a bit more persistence as long as users don't clear their browser cache or switch machines. I like to tell people to think of JupyterLite as running in a remote machine that is buried inside their browser and so to 'download' useful things they make back to their machine's normal storage. There's instructions here on how to deploy a JupyterLite offering that will also have specified packages installed already.

I will say that I have seen approaches to do what you want in Google Colab. I recently came across this post on SO asking for help getting the content away from Google Colab but the code they posted there and additional examples you can access from here show you how they run preparation steps at the top of the notebooks to insure that the environment is set up to handle things like you are asking about. See also the install.data() example there.

I forgot to add that MyBinder.org is a special Binderhub.  A Binderhub is a general term for the JupyterHub set up to specifically launch sessions with the environments and content based on repositories, not limited to GitHub. So you can use these privately with private repos, and I believe add persistence if you wanted.
